# E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView

Tags: android, multithreading, popup, handler

I'm using a java class (not an activity) that is dealing with user points calculation and checks if the user is promoted to a different title. if yes - I want to inflate a pop-up notifying the user.

- Note: I checked in similar previously asked questions *

My code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);
int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
boolean focusable = true;
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
});

popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: you need to dismiss the `popup` in `onPause` or `onDestroy` of your activity or fragment.

Comment: Where do I do that? I have a few activities that call this class.

Comment: in every activity from where you are calling this

Comment: what if from activity A I: use a toast message - > call this class -> move to activity B? I need to dismiss only in A?